# Javascript page enter event

Tags: javascript, events

I want an event this should load everytime the site is typed in the browser example : http://localhost/ is typed in the url and the first page should show is my overlay. After they read the information they can close it but if they wanna read it again they can click the button. Also if the site is getting refreshed the overlay should be popup again.

My current code and where I stuck :

```
const doc = document;
const menuOpen = doc.querySelector(".menu");
const menuClose = doc.querySelector(".close");
const overlay = doc.querySelector(".overlay");

menuOpen.addEventListener("click", () => {
  overlay.classList.add("overlay--active");
});

menuClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
  overlay.classList.remove("overlay--active");
});
```

Comment: Can you not just set the overlay active as default then?

Comment: Have you tried using `window.onload`?

Comment: Overlay just show when the button is clicked currently as you can see in the code. I'm still learning javascript and wanna learn how this could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this in javascript you can achieve this using `window.load` like this:

```
window.onload = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    overlay.classList.add("overlay--active");
}
```

but for the best solution i would think adding the `overlay--active` by default as @Keith mentioned would be nicer as this requires less javascript for the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

> You could do it by using if-else structure in javascript. Like the code I posted here. In this method you don’t need the “onload” event. And the “overlay” popped up again when the page is refreshed.

```js
var menuOpen = document.getElementById("menu");
var overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");

menuOpen.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(overlay.classList.contains("active")){
        overlay.classList.add("deactive");
        overlay.classList.remove("active");
        menuOpen.innerHTML = "show";
    } else {
        overlay.classList.add("active");
        overlay.classList.remove("deactive");
        menuOpen.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
  
});
```

```css
.active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.deactive {
    opacity: 0;
}

#menu {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #5522dd;
    color: #5522dd;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5522dd;
}

.overlay {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin-top: 25px;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript page enter event</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="overlay active">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui modi quasi, quam deleniti, placeat expedita nostrum quae quaerat? Id, velit iste saepe dolore, consequuntur vel quis iure excepturi ut aut fugit dignissimos ea magni repudiandae nihil, assumenda deleniti nostrum tenetur minima aperiam doloribus. Quaerat sunt nam distinctio! Suscipit nostrum vel, sunt, eos esse fugit.
    </div>
    
    <button id="menu">hide</button>
    
    <script src="javasc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and use it in the loading of document.
like

```
document.ready(()=>{
      $(".overlay").addClass("overlay--active");
})
```